# ios UIkit copy a UIControl

Tags: ios, uicontrol

Is there any easy way to copy an existing UI Control attribute from one to the other?  Something like

```
*button1 = *button2;
```

I know that the above will not work, but just curious.

Yes, Yes, I know can use an XIB with a view with UIControl and create controls that way.

Comment: Try to use direct copying of properties. button1.frame = button2.frame; and so on.

Comment: Yes, could do this, was looking for a one liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are ways to copy view hierarchies, they are hacky and should be avoided.

Comment: I just want to copy a button's attributes.  I guess that is too much to ask.

Comment: you could always write a helper function for it, like:

    `UIButton* CopyButton(UIButton* button) {
        UIButton* copy = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:button.frame];
       copy.property1 = button.property1;
       copy.property2 = button.property2;
       return copy;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

NSKeyedArchiver & NSKeyedUnarchiver work well for me in most cases. I've never tried to clone a control with complicated structure though.

```
extension UIView {
    func deepCopy() -> UIView {

        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
        let copy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)!  as! UIView

        return copy
    }
}
```